# Interrogate pre-commit, print results even on pass

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I'm using the interrogate pre-commit on my repo. There are a number of legacy files that don't contain doc-strings and currently the pre-commit fails when committing changes on these. Ideally, I'd like interrogate to act as a verbose warning instead of a pass/fail check.

I can use the command line argument --fail-under=0 to make it always pass but I still want to see coverage results. Is there any way that I could get the coverage results to print even when interrogate passes?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
  - repo: https://github.com/econchick/interrogate
    rev: 1.5.0
    hooks:
      - id: interrogate
        verbose: True
        args:
          - -vv
          - --fail-under=0
```

...